# Quickest way to get list of <title> values from all pages on localhost website

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler

I essentially want to spider my local site and create a list of all the titles and URLs as in:

```
http://localhost/mySite/Default.aspx      My Home Page
http://localhost/mySite/Preferences.aspx  My Preferences
http://localhost/mySite/Messages.aspx     Messages
```

I'm running Windows.  I'm open to anything that works--a C# console app, PowerShell, some existing tool, etc.  We can assume that the  tag does exist in the document.

Note:  I need to actually spider the files since the title may be set in code rather than markup.

Comment: This would be pretty easy to do with unix command line tools.  Do you have access to these, perhaps through cygwin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty Cygwin Bash script which does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find $WWWROOT -iname \*.aspx); do
  echo -en $file '\t'
  cat $file | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -i 's/.*<title>\([^<]*\)<\/title>.*/\1/'
done
```

Explanation: this finds every .aspx file under the root directory $WWWROOT, replaces all newlines with spaces so that there are no newlines between the `<title>` and `</title>`, and then grabs out the text between those tags.

Answer (score 3):

I think a script similar to [what Adam Rosenfield suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335232/quickest-way-to-get-list-of-title-values-from-all-pages-on-localhost-website#335324) is what you want, but if you want the actual URLs, try using `wget`.  With some appropriate options, it will print out a list of all the pages on your site (plus download them, which maybe you can suppress with `--spider`).  The `wget` program is avaliable through the normal Cygwin installer.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was trying to get working to post here! Here's a snippet: site=mysite.com wget --recursive --accept \*.html http://$site ;for file in $( find $site -name *.html ); do // adam's for-body

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not familiar with Windows, but to get you in the right direction: use a XSLT transformation with

<xsl:value-of select="/head/title" />
in there to get the title back or if you can, use the XPath '/head/title' to get the title back.

Answer (score 0):

I would use wget as detailed above.
Be sure you don't have any [spider traps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_trap) on your site.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using scrapy shell

check out

http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/tutorial.html

in console put something like this :

hxs.x('/html/head/title/text()').extract()

if you want all titles, you should do a spider...it really easy.

Also consider to move to linux :P